# Visual Studio 2013 Install Fails: Program Compatibility Mode is on (Windows 10)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10

I want to install Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 on my Windows 10 but I have this error:

[image]

I have done these two things (they have solved the problem on Windows 8)

[image]

[image]

but still I cannot install it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but I'm installing from an ISO.  The file is named corectly but I'm still getting this error.  Were you installing from an ISO?

Comment: I have tried all suggestions on this thread but none of the answers worked. What's going on with VS 2013 and Windows 10 ??

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Answer that worked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23114542/2352507).

They recommend checking the installer file name. It needs to be the original name oddly enough for the setup to work.

Comment: Dariusz, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23114542/2352507 They recommend checking to installer file name.

Comment: Super, thanks Sunsetquest :) installer works, after rename to "vs_ultimate"

Comment: Awesome! Great to know it worked.  I'll edit the answer in case others run into the same issue.

Comment: Great! Thanks! ...I'm just adding the german error message for some others fellows googling it like me
'Der Windows-Programmkompatibilitätsmodus ist aktiviert. Deaktivieren Sie ihn, und führen Sie Setup erneut aus.'

Comment: I encountered the same issue with VS2013 SDK. It turns out I have to stick with the original name "vssdk_full.exe", too.

Comment: This also workarounds same error when installing VS2013 SDK on Windows 10.

Comment: Worked for me too, thanks!
And is it just me, or is this dumb?!?

Comment: @smwikipedia  solution worked like a charm on Windows 10.0.16299 Build 16299. Crazy how this worked.

Comment: Works like a charm. A very, very weird charm.
Welcome to the small indie company known as Microsoft?

Comment: This is very weird that I have to rename the installer from what it downloaded as "en_visual_studio_2013_sdk_x86_3009047.exe" to "vssdk_full.exe"

Comment: @jrh - It is very weird for sure! This probably causes many issues for people including me.  Maybe it is to prevent it from being deployed under another name.. not sure.

Comment: This is odd, but funny at the same time how this kind of software works funky... I had to rename file to winexpress_full.exe to install. Great! :D

Answer (score 73):

Disabling the Program Compatibility Assistant is not the right way.

A solution that works on Windows 10 is:

- Right-click the setup file
- Select `Properties` and navigate to the `Details` tab.
- There should be an entry labeled `Original filename`. Simply rename the file accordingly and it should run.

Comment: I re-downloaded the installer from the Microsoft Store thinking it would fix the issue, it didn't. This solution was the right fix. The new downloaded installer didn't even have the correct Original file name.

Comment: Worked for me, Win10

Comment: I downloaded the VS 2013 shell from https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=shell and had to use this trick to find out the original name was "vs_isoshell.exe" After changing the name it installed.

Comment: I can't believe this is the problem.I've been searching for hours. Worked for me on Win10.

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I tried to run from a mounted ISO. exec name are okay.
I fixed the problem by copying all ISO files to the hard disk.

Answer (score 5):

right click on the installation file then navigate to the detail tab, you see the original file name there,
rename the installation file to the value of the original file name, then start installation again.

Comment: This worked for me. In my case it was 'vs_isoshell.exe'. These steps enable selection of the correct filename..

Answer (score 3):

If changing the name did not work run setup with `\layout` argument.

Answer (score 2):

Copy the installation files into your hard drive.
Rename the installer file name to vs_professional.exe for professional edition.
Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Just extract the ISO file to hard drive and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Windows 10 and korean version of Visual studio. I wanted to change from korean to english. I downloaded the english language pack but  the error message appeared as "compatibility mode is on..." the only solution to this issue is to rename the Language pack setup file name with its original name, that is to say vs_langpack.exe . And boom the issue is solved.

Hope it is helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the below source you should do the follwong:

> Go to the installation folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE", find the executable file(If your VS express
>   2013 is VS express 2013 for web, the executable file is
>   VWDExpress.exe).
>
> Right-click the file, select the tab "compatibility". Disable all
>   compatibility settings over here

So , please try to disable any component 'compatibility' settings (turning off the compatibility service is not enough in that case).

Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1985a3dd-f12d-4d08-ba8a-51535a3c8dc9/visual-stodio-2013-express-cannot-be-installed?forum=vssetup

In addition, can you upload the installing log?

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Download the Microsoft Visual Studio and .NET Framework Log
   Collection tool (collect.exe). -
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493
2. Run the collect.exe tool from the directory where you saved the
   tool.
3. The utility creates a compressed cabinet file of all the VS and .NET
   logs to %TEMP%\vslogs.cab.
4. Post the vslogs.cab

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2899270

Answer (score 0):

If you disable the Program Compatibility Mode and the problem persists, copy the content of ISO to a local path and try install with a simple double click

Answer (score 0):

In my case also works to download ISO and copy all files from ISO to hard drive. It works for Visual Studio Community 2015 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should try extract your file and setup after there.

I had trouble with Mount to virtual drive by ISO and the same with RAR file. But when I extract it, it work fine

Answer (score 0):

For reference: I had this error when trying to do an unattended VS 2013 install in a `windowsservercore` docker container:

```
.\vs_professional.exe /Q
```

reason turned out to be having the installation files on a docker volume, copying to the disk of the container solved it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing from an ISO file by mounting it on a Virtual Drive, Just copy the files from the Virtual Drive to your hard disk. Run the installer, it will definitely work. I have solved my problem.

Comment: There is no information in the question about OP installing from an ISO