# visual studio 2013 windows program compatibility mode

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I install windows 10 , after i install visual studio 2013 ultimate
bat cannot run VS2013  setup 
Error - windows program compatibility mode is on. turn it off and then try setup again
pleas help me solve problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 Install Fails: Program Compatibility Mode is on (Windows 10)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225146/visual-studio-2013-install-fails-program-compatibility-mode-is-on-windows-10)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and tried every solution on the internet but none of them worked for me.
(my setup file was a `.iso` file that I mounted on a virtual disk.)
I simply copied the files from virtual drive to one of my hard drives and ran the setup again: it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on your file installer visual studio .exe then properties>details> look at the Originil file name, rename visual studio installer using the same name in  originil file name. Run it and it work...!

i hope this work...

Comment: I was able to get the web installer to work by doing this