# Visual Studio 2013 Language Pack Install Fails: Program Compatibility Mode is on (Windows 10)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, virtual-machine, windows-10, vmware, compatibility-mode

I had to install VS2013 on a Windows 10 VM (VMWare).
My prblem similar to this question, which helped me before: [Visual Studio 2013 Install Fails: Program Compatibility Mode is on (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225146/visual-studio-2013-install-fails-program-compatibility-mode-is-on-windows-10)

The solution was to rename the VS installer (in my Case to "vs_premium.exe").

But now I also need to install a VS2013 language pack.
The language pack fails by the same error, but it is named correctly ("vs_langpack.exe"), so that the "old solution" from the named thread doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Change file name to "vssdk_full.exe"

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but just ran into a similar problem and none of the SO answers so far helped, so maybe this solution helps someone else: I had run the compatibility troubleshooter at some point in the past, but there was no compatibility tab under properties to reset compatibility mode, nor did disabling the troubleshooter help.

It turned out the troubleshooter had installed a directory for Microsoft Visual Studio under Program Files (in addition to the default in Program Files (x86)). Deleting this directory solved the problem.