# Installing VS2013 on Win10

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-10

My institution pays for a DreamSpark expanded catalog to include VS2013 Pro.  I'm working to finally make the move from Win7 to Win10 on our lab's main development machine.  When I run the installer, the error pops "Windows Program Compatibility mode is on. Turn it off and then try setup again," but I've even checked compatibility mode manually and it's not running.

**Edit:** [Looking at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949411/visual-studio-2012-install-fails-program-compatibility-mode-is-on/23114542#23114542), I note that the name hasn't been changed from the DL from Dream Spark "en_vs_professional."

Nether did running it in Win8 or Win7 compatibility help.

I was able to install VS2015 community w/o issue, but as most of projects have been going in VS2013, I'd rather continue there (and I think VS12 Pro has more features than VS13 Community).

The relevant part of the error log seems to be:

```
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (WindowsBuildNumber < 9600)' evaluates to false.
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i052: Condition 'CompatibilityMode = 0' evaluates to true.
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i052: Condition 'NOT((VersionNT > v6.1) OR (VersionNT = v6.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1))' evaluates to false.
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i052: Condition '(NOT IsLanguagePack) AND ( CurrentOperation = "Install" ) AND ( FLP_Version > v12.0.21005 )' evaluates to false.
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i052: Condition 'RebootPending = 1' evaluates to false.
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i052: Condition 'NOT (IEsvcVersionExists) OR (IEsvcVersion < v10.0)' evaluates to false.
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i052: Condition '(VersionNT < v6.2) AND ((NetworkAvailable = 0) OR (DisableRootAutoUpdate = 1)) AND NOT ((MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2011RootExists OR MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2011AuthRootExists) AND (MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2010RootExists OR MicrosoftRootCertificateAuthority2010AuthRootExists))' evaluates to false.
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i052: Condition 'CurrentOperation = "Install" AND (PremiumCore_Version < v12.0.21003 OR UltimateCore_Version < v12.0.21003)' evaluates to false.
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i052: Condition '(VersionNT = v6.3) AND (netfxfullredist_43_DetectKey < v4.5.50709)' evaluates to false.
[1954:1768][2016-05-06T08:34:46]i000: MUX:  Stop Block: CompatibilityMode : Windows Program Compatibility mode is on. Turn it off and then try Setup again.
```

I tried the installer (freshly downloaded) on an older Win7 build and didn't have an issue, but I haven't been able to get a Win10 install to go.

Any pointers would be great (eventually the high level IT support from institution will get to me, but I suspect this will be faster).

Comment: You may want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23114542/2144471) - looks like compatibility issues come out if the VS installer is anyway renamed

Comment: The file wasn't renamed, it came as directly from Dream Spark "en_vs_professional" it's the web installer.

Comment: I just realized that if I checked the details that the "original filename" was vs_professional, which is a hysterical problem to me, because it came straight from MS with that file name.  I had heard that before, but I misunderstood that to be due to the user changing the filename, not MS>

Comment: weird enough, but M$ used us to weird stuff :-)